# three.js normal issue after exporting from the three.js editor

Tags: three.js

I have a Model baked in Modo. With all normal's pointing outside. I convert it with the threejs editor.
But when i view the model with the normal map aplied. The normal's look wrong.
see [flipped right, correct left]: http://www.avezaat.net/normalIssue.jpg
The normal-map is correct on the left and wrong on the right.

I have solved it by adding:

```
material.normalScale.x = -1;
material.normalScale.y = -1;
```

But i rather not to. Can someone ex-plane to me what i do wrong and how to fix it in Modo?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inverting the normal scale is pretty much the only thing you can do. -1 is a normal value for the normal mapping.